Optimization of a macro that looks for structures and materials on a worksheet and sums the total on another worksheet
I work on an electric company that builds power distribution systems that uses standard electrical structures with predefine materials on it.Every structure has an unique identifier.
So I made a workbook with 3 worksheets on it.
The first one is a table of each pole with their respective list structures on it, that is generated by a autocad drawing.
(example: Pole 1 has structure A, B, C.
          Pole 2 has structure B, D, F
          Pole 3 has structure A, C, F)

The second worksheet has a table that contains columns with the standard materials that all structures have.
(example                 A    B   C   D   F
         Material 1      1    0   0   1   1
         Material 2      0    0   3   0   1
         Material 3      2    2   1   0   0 
         Material 4      0    1   0   4   0 )

The third worksheet contains a table with the sum of all the material of each pole.
(example                 Pole 1    Pole2   Pole3
                         A+B+C     B+D+F   A+C+F
         Material 1        1         2       2   
         Material 2        3         1       4   
         Material 3        5         2       3   
         Material 4        1         5       0   )  

I made a macro on excel VBA that iterate every structure present on worksheet 1, then finds the range of materials on worksheet 2 and sums the total on worksheet 3, but is very slow.
Usually I have at least 100 poles with 7 or 8 structures on every one, and every structure has 50 items on it, so it takes up to 8 minutes to do simple sums. and the material database has up to 500 structures listed there.
PD. Sorry for my english.
Here is some code that I use.
Sub Iteration()
    Dim sourcews As Worksheet
    Dim targetws As Worksheet
 
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim cellValue As Integer
    
    
    Set sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKSHEET1") 
    
    
    rowCount = sourcews.Cells(sourcews.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    colCount = sourcews.Cells(1, sourcews.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 


    
    For r = 1 To rowCount
        
            For i = 1 To 25
                If sourcews.Cells(r, i + 10).Value <> "" Then
                    cellValue = Right(sourcews.Cells(r, 5).Value, Len(sourcews.Cells(r, 5).Value) - 1)
                    Call SumColumnData(cellValue, sourcews.Cells(r, 5).Value, sourcews.Cells(r, i + 10).Value)
                End If
            Next i
        
    Next r



End Sub


Sub SumColumnData(cellPost As Integer, numPost As String, estr As String)

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim headerName As String
    Dim targetHeader As String
    Dim sourceColumn As Range
    Dim targetColumn As Range
    Dim sourceHeaderCell As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRowSource As Long
    Dim lastRowTarget As Long
    Dim targetHeaderCell As Range
    
    
    
    ' Set references to the sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKSHEET2") 
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKSHEET3") 

    ' Find the column with the specified header in the source sheet
        If Right(estr, 1) = "r" Then
            Set sourceHeaderCell = sourceSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=Left(estr, Len(estr) - 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Else
            Set sourceHeaderCell = sourceSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=estr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        End If
    
    
    If Not sourceHeaderCell Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the range for the column below the header
        lastRowSource = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, sourceHeaderCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set sourceColumn = sourceSheet.Range(sourceHeaderCell.Offset(1, 0), sourceSheet.Cells(lastRowSource, sourceHeaderCell.Column))
        
        'Find the column with the specified header in the target sheet
        If Right(estr, 1) = "r" Then
            Set targetHeaderCell = targetSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, cellPost * 2 + 8)
        Else
            Set targetHeaderCell = targetSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, cellPost * 2 + 7)
        End If
        
        If Not targetHeaderCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Get the range for the target column
            lastRowTarget = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, targetHeaderCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Set targetColumn = targetSheet.Range(targetHeaderCell.Offset(13, 0), targetSheet.Cells(lastRowTarget, targetHeaderCell.Column))
            
            ' Sum the values from the source column and add to the target column
            For Each cell In sourceColumn
                If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                    targetSheet.Cells(cell.Row + 12, targetHeaderCell.Column).Value = targetSheet.Cells(cell.Row + 12, targetHeaderCell.Column).Value + cell.Value
                End If
            Next cell

            
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Could you help me do this more efficient. I think accesing the worksheet 2 every time I have to find every structure and the sum on worksheet 3 make it so slow.
I read I should use arrays instead of ranges to store the base of materials but I dont know how to do that.

What does the "r" mean on the end of the structure ID ?

probably (r)ow and (c)olumn

loading data into memory at the start ONCE and not accessing the Cells using Range over and over again could speed it up. see this post for some ideas with array/dictionary: VBA Dictionary with Dynamic Arrays
you can also measure the runtime of parts of your code for example nested loops. you can do this by using Timer, for example:
StartTime = Timer
'possibly extensive code here
Debug.Print "SecondsElapsed: " & (Timer - StartTime)

you can also debug the code to make sure you aren't accessing unnecessary Cells. i personally dont trust the xlUp and xlToLeft ;-)
Debug.Print rowCount
Debug.Print colCount

give Named Ranges a try (https://trumpexcel.com/named-ranges-in-excel/). you can access them in VBA pretty straigt forward (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges)

I use this to make an array, it's kept as simple as possible, I hate coming back to old code and then having to spend time to relearn what some obscure function did.
Dim cx As Integer, cy As Integer
Dim Arr() As Double
cx = 1 'Column counter
cy = 1 'Row counter


'get size for array
Do 'row loop
        cy = cy + 1
Loop Until ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(cy, 1) = ""


Do 'column loop
    cx = cx + 1
Loop Until ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cx) = ""

ReDim Arr(cy - 2, cx - 2)

cx = 1
cy = 1

'Fill array
Do
    Do 'column loop
        Arr(cy - 1, cx - 1) = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(cy, cx)
        cx = cx + 1
    Loop Until ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cx) = ""
    cy = cy + 1
    cx = 1
Loop Until ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(cy, 1) = ""


this code's loop break on an empty cell, while the original code just kept working. depending on the data this could result in new problems.

hmm not a bad idea, Ill change it to loop over the dimensions of the array in the final part (fill array)

iirc i always tried a few more empty cells before breaking the loop

With formula of 365 you can test speed.
It uses the second and third table.
Range is the second table
Range2 is Pole1 content (the cell below the name)
Cell F16: =A7:A10
Cell G16:
=LET(range,$A$6:$F$10,
range2,B$15,
title, DROP(CHOOSECOLS(range,1),1),
singlecol,DROP(CHOOSECOLS(range,MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(range2,"+"),CHOOSEROWS(range,1),0)),1),
res,SUM(VALUE(CHOOSEROWS(singlecol,MATCH($A7,CHOOSECOLS(range,1),0)-1))),
res)

Copy to right and then the row down on the range

